# How to control multiple instances of the same pthread to process a sequential list

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, mutex

I have a linked list which will be processed by ***n*** instances of the same ***pthread***.

The thread will continuously remove an item from the list and depending on the type will move it to a second list, assigning it a sequential reference number which is generated by a function. The numbers must be assigned in the same sequence as the items are removed from the list.

I would appreciate some ideas on how to go about this. The problem is that the threads are assigning out of order reference numbers to the items removed from the list. Please consider a list containing A1, A2, A3. Thread ***n1*** removes A1, gets reference number 1 and associates it with item A1. Thread ***n2*** removes item A2 and thread ***n3*** removes item A3; before thread ***n2*** can get reference number 2, thread ***n3*** already got it and therefore when thread ***n2*** gets the reference number it will be reference number 3.

The result is: {{A1, 1}, {A2, 3}, {A3, 2}} which is incorrect. I have tried using a condition variable, but the only way that it makes sense to me would be to call *pthread_cond_broadcast()* before calling *pthread_cond_wait()*, which obviously is illogical, the idea being something like *do not let any thread get an item from the list until the last item is processed*. I have implemented a version which skips the pthread_cond_signal() if it's the very first thread to run and then hits the pthread_cond_wait() until the second thread runs pthread_cond_broadcast(); it works better than without the condition variable but the results are not constant. Sometimes will work perfectly for 2 or 3 threads, sometimes for 2 or 4, but obviously it's not working. I have also used a mutex variable but was not able to accomplish the objective.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you have each thread lock a mutex, remove a list element, associate the list element with its number, then unlock the mutex?

Comment: I figured out the problem; still need to find an adequate solution. The pthreads are being created inside a loop. When the second, third, fourth, etc., thread is created it it is not aware of the mutex lock done by thread 1 and therefore does not respect it; it goes right through it. I need to make all the threads wait for the last one before they start processing.

Comment: Got it... using pthread_cond_wait got all the threads waiting for a signal to run. Created a dummy pthread that did a pthread_cond_broadcast once loaded. Worked perfectly.

Comment: pthread_barrier... Beautiful!